# How to get the position of toggle button clicked within listview?

Tags: android, listview, alarmmanager, togglebutton

I have a listview that contains alarm times and a toggle button to turn off/on that alarm. When I click the toggle buttons for the specific listview, I would like to set/cancel that specific alarm. But how do I get the position of the listview I clicked on based on the view?

When I click my toggle button on/off it hits this code:

```
public void enableAlarm(View view) {

    // set/cancel alarm manager pending intent
}
```

I have some information stored for each particular listview item in a Database, but I need the listview position. How can I get the position from the view?

Comment: are you using custom adapter for listview.?

Comment: Array adapter, I have a setOnItemClick for the listview items, but that isnt hit for the actual toggle buttons.

Comment: setOnItemClick for complete row not for subviews of row . i think you should use custom adapter.

Comment: Just extend array adapter and add some handling for the toggle button?

Comment: yes. make custom row for listview inflate that row in getview. then find toggle button from view and add listener on it. :)

Comment: Cool. Know any resources where this is implemented?

Comment: you can find something helpful here http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429 and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: set a tag with position on your toggle button

Comment: @pskink within the custom adapter?

Comment: toggleButton.setTag(position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create a custom `ArrayAdapter` class and override the `getView()` method. From that method, you have access to the position of the list item from which the toggle was set, and can create a unique `OnCheckedChangeListener` for each toggle button, passing it the position of the list.

I'm assuming you already have an XML layout file for whatever is supposed to be held in each ListView item, since you mention an alarm and toggle buttons.

**Update:**
In order to get the alarm time and send it to the `enableAlarm()` method, you need to save it as a `final` variable within `getView()` so you can access it within the `onCheckedChangeListener`. Look at the code I added after getting the ToggleButton.

```
@override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getContext().getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_item, parent, false);
    }
    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);

    //get the alarm time
    TextView timeView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.theAlarmTextView);
    final String alarmTime = timeView.getText();

    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                //modify your enableAlarm method to take in the time as a String
                enableAlarm(buttonView, alarmTime);
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: If I am using the on/off toggle to enable or disable the alarm, is it okay to create a datasource inside the adapter to get the alarm date/time?

Comment: It seems that the inflation of the layout is causing the textview to disappear in my listview. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The textView within each individual list item, or the TextView above your ListView? You might have to change some `fill_parent` or `match_parent` values to `wrap_content`